# How to store Various Data (Array of object) in Android using SharedPreference

Tags: android, android-preferences

I am very new in android development application and java too.My application need to store define places which should contain (name, latitude, longitude, ringtonepreference). The ui will be ListView and 1st view should be "click here to add more places". After clicking on setting ui should come.After click on defined places should come defined setting.

I hope anyone solve my problem.I'm waiting for response .Thanks you in advance

Comment: So whats the question???

Comment: Not enough information to analyze your problem